# С чего начать обучение языку Java?

Tags: java

Здравствуйте!
Я решился сесть учить Java, но нормальных обучалок так и не нашел(Да и с математикой плохо).Гугл не помог.
Хотелось бы спросить, где можно найти нормальные уроки по Java, где все детально разжевано?

Comment: Есть книга, рассчитанная на детей среднего возраста: Я. Файн - "Программирование на Java для детей, родителей, дедушек и бабушек" - 2001 . Если и она будет сложной, то не ваше это все.

Comment: Можете кидать камнями, но лично я начинал заниматься явой с уроков [Юрия Ткача](http://pastebin.com/bjYzRNsN), только потом пересев на книги. Основные вещи он рассказывает очень даже хорошо, но если посмотреть видео, где он копает поглубже, то без начальной подготовки будет трудновато понять.

Comment: Что касается математики. Если хотите работать в IT, то математику рано или придется подкачать. И английский тоже. Морально готовьтесь любить и изучать эти области. Исключение — если вы мечтаете всю жизнь делать сайтики. Тогда достаточно арифметики.

Comment: "Изучаем Java" Кэти Сиерра, Берт Бейтс для новичка самый лучший вариант. Не лишним будет пройти 10 бесплатных уровней на [javarush](http://javarush.ru/).

Comment: @pavlofff кое в чём в она безумна сложна - в ней предлагают вначале скомпилировать и запустить хеллоуворлд БЕЗ ИДЕ, вручную! Я до сих пор так не умею, ну по крайней мере без туториала(...

Comment: Из видео мне нравится как рассказывает [Иван Головач](http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCuIctN7x71qam9K_ZxS1W2A).
По книжкам можно посмотреть [Шилдта](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31249554/), ну и, конечено же, классика жанра [Эккель](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/30425811/). Лично моей первой книгой по java был [Хорстман](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/25151213/) - однако для начала нахожу его тяжеловатым по стилю изложения.
Главное, не сдаваться. Надеюсь, найдешь то, что подойдет именно тебе.